# Can't deploy application in Jboss7, with spring and hibernate, postgresql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jboss7.x

I can't deploy my application on Jboss 7.1.1, I'm using Spring 4.1.2.RELEASE.

I have error like :

```
14:08:39,106 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [config/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/CascadeStyles$BaseCascadeStyle
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/CascadeStyles$BaseCascadeStyle
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:486) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:208) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) [spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) [spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) [spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) [spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles$BaseCascadeStyle from [Module "deployment.acquirer.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 29 more
```

My persistance.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- Has to exist. Config inside applicationContext.xml -->
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and jboss development structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>  
        <dependencies>  
          <module name="org.hibernate" />  
          <module name="org.hibernate.envers" />  
          <module name="org.hibernate.validator" /> 
          <module name="org.postgresql"/>
        </dependencies>  
        <resources>  
            <resource-root path="hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar"/>  
            <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar"/>   
            <resource-root path="hibernate-envers-4.3.7.Final.jar"/>  
            <resource-root path="hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar"/>  
        </resources>  
       </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and this is my applicatinContext.xml:

```
<!-- database init -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"></property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <!-- hibernate config -->
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy"
                value="org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy" />
            <entry
                key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp"
                value="true" />
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision"
                value="true" />
            <entry key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes" value="true" />
            <entry key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone" value="jvm" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

and pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.fenige</groupId>
    <artifactId>acquirer</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>acquirer Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jboss -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>acquirer</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

btw. my application working with tomcat server, but not working with Jboss.I tried a lot of things , and i cant find solution for my problem

Thanks for answers

Comment: I don't know how to resolve your problem, but JBoss7 already have OSGI bundles for Hibernate 4 and 3, you can use Hibernate from JBoss. You can add dependency in pom.xml for MANIFEST file: org.hibernate, org.hibernate.envers and set scope to <provided> for hibernate jars.

Comment: i did this what you said, and now i'm getting error like . `Error creating bean with name 'authorizationCommunicationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: acquirer.service.authorization.mc.CommunicationServiceImpl .acquirer.controller.mc.AuthorizationCommunicationController.communicationS`

Comment: Add  org.javassist to dependency

Comment: Thx for suggestion, but yesterday , i resolved my problem :)

Comment: @Murder Can you tell me how you resolved your issue. I am facing same issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, I think I did something with libraries inside JBoss. I am not remember exactly what I did.