# can't deploy my application on Jboss 7.1.1 working on Tomcat 7

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I can't deploy my application on Jboss 7.1.1 which is working on Tomcat 7, I'm using Hibernate 4.  I have error like :

```
18:15:25,932 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles$BaseCascadeStyle in Module "deployment.traccar-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:486) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:208) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:131) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.start(JpaPersistService.java:94) [guice-persist-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter.init(PersistFilter.java:77) [guice-persist-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:114) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:98) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

18:15:25,932 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/traccar-web]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception starting filter guiceFilter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/spi/CascadeStyles$BaseCascadeStyle
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:486) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:208) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:131) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.start(JpaPersistService.java:94) [guice-persist-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter.init(PersistFilter.java:77) [guice-persist-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:114) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:98) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles$BaseCascadeStyle from [Module "deployment.traccar-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 23 more

18:15:25,947 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error filterStart
18:15:25,947 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context [/traccar-web] startup failed due to previous errors
18:15:25,963 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./traccar-web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./traccar-web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: I already checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855495/cant-deploy-application-in-jboss7-with-spring-and-hibernate-postgresql, but still struggling :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this posting (you will need to translate it to English):
http://www.guj.com.br/8783-exception-jpahibernate